# convert type number to type string

Tags: typescript

If I have an array of numbers, but want to change the types so it's an array of strings (with the same values), how should I go about this?

```
const a = [
    1,
    2,
    3
] as const

type k = Array<typeof a[number]> // want this to become `("1" | "2" | "3")[]`
```

How do I change it so that it's an array of strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a "serializable" type `T`, that is, a subtype of `string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined`, then you can convert it to its string literal representation via the [template literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) `` `${T}` ``.  In your case, you have `typeof a[number]` as `1 | 2 | 3`, so you can write `` `${typeof a[number]}` `` to convert it to `"1" | "2" | "3"`:

```
const a = [
    1,
    2,
    3
] as const

type K = Array<`${typeof a[number]}`>;
// type K = ("1" | "2" | "3")[]
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA2gKBpmBGANBrAJnyxgGY0BdeCGUSKNNKATwAcBTGAaSRgEEAToLgsAPAAMAJAG9WnEADN4KMAFcAtgCMOgygF8JAPgDcaAPTmY8rr2QAKAETZHMAD4xHhVx8dlHAJQolEA)

Answer (score 2):

Create a utility type that maps the Array keys and convert their values type to the const string array type :

```js
const a = [
    1,
    2,
    3
] as const;

type ConverToConstStringArray<T extends readonly number[]> = {
    [K in keyof T]: `${T[K]}`;
};
type strArr = ConverToConstStringArray<typeof a>;
```

Or use the infer and convert the numbers to strings recursively :

```js
type ConverToConstStringArray<T extends readonly number[]> = 
T extends readonly [infer A, ...infer B]? [`${A}`, ...ConverToConstStringArray<B>]: [];
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA2gKAJAEYA0mBMeGAzGgLrwQyiRQDcaaUAngA4CmMAwuAG7sAnACogetAMpQBASzABzAIICBcZgB4hMdgA8o7MABMqA9nAPgANsxhgArgFsARoJRkAfEhgBvNDD+oAaRhZGABrdmYQADMYITIALhgAAwASLyEUALIAXySGbIYWDm4+QRExaEkZeSUVZnwNLV19IxgTM0trOycXd09NHT1DY1NzMCtUWSjBGAUcGAA6JamZgCEyAH5UVK8FXPmlhbF+YVFwSqlZRWVVNVW3BNQyBiY2TkdkY7KziUuam-qaiK7Gi8DcDH8AHpIQA9DZAA)

Comment: This leaves it as just `string[]`, I'm looking to change it to another readonly with the same values (but as a string), e.g. `("1" | "2" | "3")[]`. I'll update my question to better reflect what I want